# Adding custom field to identitymodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have added a new field to MVC's identity model,

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public int JeAdmin { get; set; }
    public Ekipa Ekipa { get; set; }
}
```

My ekipa class consists of the following:

```
     public class Ekipa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public int LeaderID { get; set; }
    public int Geslo { get; set; }

}
```

How do I set an object, which I get from database, to the logged in user?
I get the current user,

```
     ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        EkipaDb db1 = new EkipaDb();
        currentUser.Ekipa = db1.Ekipa.Where(m => m.id == 1);
```

How do I get the object from EkipaDb where id is 1, and add it to the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an object to a database table's column - but you can add a foreign key.

Add:

```
public int EkipaId { get; set; }
```

And make the Ekipa object virtual:

```
[ForeignKey("EkipaId")]
public virtual Ekipa Ekipa { get; set; }
```

This will store the `Id` of the `Epika` object in the `ApplicationUser` table, and you can use the navigation property to retrieve the object itself when loading the `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was somehow possible in MVC. :)